# Chrome not displaying input type validation messages inside modal

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angularJS as mvc and [UI bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for modal views. The problem is that chrome doesn't show validation messages of input types.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Input validation works for me in chrome. Please check out the following link in chrome. http://jsbin.com/jipagovo/2/edit?html,output

Comment: I'm talking about modal views...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I tried again (http://plnkr.co/edit/nXOWZvDIazwbMg9si2B2?p=preview) using a modal in angular-ui and i still get input validation. Is this what you referring to?

Comment: +1
I am having the same issue. Any update on this?